# Sort values of "totalsForAllResults" of google analytics API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I extracted the data from the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) and wrote it to spreadsheet using Apps Script. At the end of the row, I pushed out total values of each metrics using `totalsForAllResults` method.

But I have problem, the order of total value doesn't correspond to each metric name.

For example, at the end of the column of `sessions`, there is total value of `bounces` but it should be the total of `sessions`.

I need help to sort total values as it correspond to each metrics:

```
function getReportDataForProfile(firstProfile) {

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = getLastNdays(14);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:keyword',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'sort': '-ga:sessions,ga:keyword',       // Sort by sessions descending, then keyword.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '20'                     // Display the first 250 results.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
    'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactionRevenuePerSession', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);
}
function outputToSpreadsheet(results) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();

  // Print the headers.
  var headerNames = [];
  for (var i = 0, header; header = results.getColumnHeaders()[i]; ++i) {
    headerNames.push(header.getName());
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headerNames.length)
      .setValues([headerNames]);

  // Print the rows of data.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
      .setValues(results.getRows());

//Print the total Value
 var data = [];
 var totals = results.totalsForAllResults;
  for (metricName in totals) {
    data.push(totals[metricName]);
  }
 var row = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 var col = sheet.getLastColumn()-1;
  sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, col).setValues([data]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, an object's properties are not ordered, so the following code is causing your problem:

```
for (metricName in totals) {
  data.push(totals[metricName]);
}
```

The metric names in the `totals` object are most likely not going to be in the same order as the column headers.

To keep the order consistent, always refer to the `columnHeaders` array (which you did elsewhere in your code).

You could rewrite the above code block as follows:

```
for (var i = 0, header; header = results.columnHeaders[i]; i++) {
  data.push(results.totalsForAllResults[header.name]);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I could never known without your answer. Thank you.